# Change Scroll target from GMSMapView to ScrollView once maps goes out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, gmsmapview

I have a GMSMapView inside a scrollView. I set bounds to the mapView.
Is there a way to make the scrolling transition from GMSMapView to ScrollView smooth and correct?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        var latitude  = position.target.latitude;
        var longitude = position.target.longitude;

        //northEast out of bounds Latitude (top out of bounds)
        if (position.target.latitude > northEastLatitude) {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100), animated: true)
            latitude = northEastLatitude;

        }

        //southWest out of bounds Latitude (bottom out of bounds)
        if (position.target.latitude < southWestLatitude) {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), animated: true)
            latitude = southWestLatitude;

        }

        //northEast out of bounds Longitude (right out of bounds)
        if (position.target.longitude > nortEastLongitude) {
            longitude = nortEastLongitude;

        }

        //southWest out of bounds Longitude (left out of bounds)
        if (position.target.longitude < southWestLongitude) {
            longitude = southWestLongitude;
        }

        if (latitude != position.target.latitude || longitude != position.target.longitude) {
            var l = CLLocationCoordinate2D();
            l.latitude  = latitude;
            l.longitude = longitude;
            mapView.animate(toLocation: l);
        }
    }
```

The setContentOffset is working but doesn't look very good.
In the event scrolls top out of bounds or bot out of bounds the scroll should continue on the ScrollView.

Comment: MapView have its own scrollview to scroll the map, why you take external scrollView? Is there any specified requirement?

Comment: The mapView scrolls perfectly on its own, but I want the scroll to continue on the parent scrollView once the map scrolling reaches out of bounds.

Comment: I dont think map have boundary, its content always scroll. Or may be something you trying to do that I am not getting